# How to enable log print for omniture library android

Tags: android, adobe-analytics

I am using ADMS (omniture) library library in android, I want to enable the logs of request and response of omniture  library, so that i can track what is exchanged with server, my custom app state is not visible in server reporting, I need to find where is the problem.

In ios omniture logs are printed on console, but how to enable logs in android. Any help is greatly welcomed... please help me.

I using the following code

```
ADMS_Measurement measurement = ADMS_Measurement.sharedInstance();
measurement.trackAppState(appState, contextData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
ADMS_Measurement measurement = ADMS_Measurement.sharedInstance(activity);
        measurement.setDebugLogging(true);
        measurement.configureMeasurement(TRACKING_RSID, TRACKING_SERVER);
```